# How to enable CORS on Orchard CMS?

Tags: cors, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I'm new to orchard cms. I've created a custom module with api controller. The only problem is I can't get the data from api when I use cross domain

Comment: I have the same problem. I don't know how to access HttpConfiguration. The ControllerContext.Configuration property is always null. Did u find a solution for this?Thx

Comment: The comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30285159/access-httpconfiguration-in-orchard-cms) from @DanielLeiszen is a good answer to this question.

Answer (score 2):

I had added the below lines of code on Global.asax of Orchard.Web and it works

```
protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("X-Frame-Options");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is one trick that you don't need to break the original orchard source. You catch and response the preflight request with expected config.

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    [HttpOptions]
    public HttpResponseMessage EnableCors()
    {
        var response = Request.CreateResponse();
        response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "your client");
        response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "methods");
        response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "content-type");
        return response;
    }
```

}