# Access HttpConfiguration in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I would like to enable CORS (Cross-Origin Request) in Orchard 1.8.1. I followed [this article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api) for the purpose. However, I don't know how to access HttpConfiguration for my WebAPI Controller. I tried to use ControllerContext.Configuration, but it seems to be always NULL.

What is the proper method to access HttpConfiguration in Orchard and to call EnableCors()?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: As I figured Orchard uses GlobalConfiguration, I created a shell hook impelmenting the IOrchardShellEvents in my module, and inside the Activated method implementation I called System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnableCors();

Comment: That's exactly it. You should post this as the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I figured Orchard uses GlobalConfiguration, I created a shell hook impelmenting the IOrchardShellEvents in my module, and inside the Activated method implementation I called System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnableCors();